# Create component variables that rely on state? Best practise?

Tags: reactjs

I am having a problem and I am wondering if there is a best practise for this.

Here is an example component:

```
class Example extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            something: 'initial'
        }
    }

    getDataUnit() {
      return({
        valueA: 'foo',
        valueB: this.state.something,
      })
    }

    exampleMethod() {
      const data = getDataUnit()
      exampleFunction(dataUnit)
    }

    render(){
      const data = getDataUnit()
      return(
         <div example={dataUnit}>
             Something
         </div>
      )
    }
}
```

As you can see I am using the `dataUnit` at multiple places within the component and `dataUnit` also relies on the component state (so I can't put it in the constructor). To get the dataUnit I implemented a function to retrieve it every time I use it. This seems a bit sub-optimal. Is there a "cleaner" solution to this or a best practise?

This might be trivial but I have had this issue in multiple projects now.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If a change of a value should be reflected in the UI it should be put in the state. Separate methods can be created to transform data to various formats

Comment: So I am just having the situation that I am using the same data object `dataUnit` in many places of the component and am I trying to find a way not to reconstruct the same object `dataUnit` in every method again and again. The object that I want to construct contains values that belong to the state of the component as well as props and e. g. values from context API. Maybe the function from my question is already the right way to do it. I don't know.

Comment: What happens with the final dataUnit object? If the entire object is used as result is it fine to store it in state. Keep in mind props can change and you will have update the state yourself

Comment: But where do you see the problem with that? If the props or state changes the component will be re-rendered giving the function access to the current value of all the attributes.

Comment: That's true, the code you provided seems fine. It is just a warning that you have to keep the possible changes from props in mind. I would suggest to keep going with your current approach. Possible problems will arise and can be fixed by tuning your current approach

Comment: Ok, thanks. Also, thanks for taking the time to look at it!